# As a client,where can i give feedback on Salesforce spring 18 release to Salesforce?

Tags: spring18

As a client,where can i give feedback on Salesforce spring 18 release to Salesforce?Some of the features we dont like.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not the right place for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few ways are standard these days.

## Chatter Groups

Go to [Success](https://success.salesforce.com/), click on Collaboration, and find a Chatter Group that matches your feature (e.g. Chatter Groups Feedback and Discussion), and post a comment there.

## Help and Training

Go to Help & Training, click on Support, and log a case. Technical Support will escalate the case and it will (eventually) be routed to the people responsible for a particular product/feature.

## Account Executive/Customer Success Manager

If you have a CSM, talk to them; they can direct you to the appropriate person. Similarly, your AE should be able to get you in touch with the appropriate person.

Answer (score 1):

to Further expand:

Via the [Help & Training Portal](https://help.salesforce.com/home) at the bottom (page footer):
[image]

you can see there are plenty of contact links, most notably **Contact Support** as mentioned in
@sfdcfox 's post,

**Social Media** can also be used to provide feedback & there a re a couple of phone numbers tlisted there, which I am sure you could try. (I have personally never called Salesforce, so I am clueles as to what options they provide over the phone).

Answer (score 0):

You can also create an Idea in [Idea Exchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch) with the features you want to be "changed" or "added".

Using Idea Exchange, you can suggest new features, vote and comment on other Ideas as well.

Comment: And wait for years for them to never be implemented lol